# This puzzle you must solve

Tags: pattern, knowledge

Can you add 2 numbers to this pattern ?

> 10730
>   11823
>   12922
>   2701
>   3793
>   4892
>   16787

Hint 1

> The first part of this pattern is certain but the answer is not

Hint 2

> You can only add 2 numbers at the end at the moment. But if you take too much time to solve this, you may have to find more...

Comment: Of course, I can add like a million numbers to it. Are we completing a pattern? At the end? The beginning? Digits in the middle?

Comment: @Raystafarian I have added a new hint and a new tag, I hope it is clearer

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of knowledge we need? Or would it make it too easy for us?

Comment: Interpreting these as post IDs seemed to lead somewhere, but they point to a lot of deleted posts. Both the second and the third (now deleted) are answering "decimal point" to two different questions though...

Comment: @Deusovi Since OP doesn't have 2000 rep to view deleted posts, I don't think that's on the right track.

Comment: @Deusovi No post IDs involved here

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The numbers mean

> 10730 days after 1/1/1970: [May 19, 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_%E2%80%93_The_Phantom_Menace)
>  11823 days after 1/1/1970: [May 16, 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_%E2%80%93_Attack_of_the_Clones)
>  12922 days after 1/1/1970: [May 19, 2005](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_%E2%80%93_Revenge_of_the_Sith)
>  2701 days after 1/1/1970: [May 25, 1977](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_%28film%29)
>  3793 days after 1/1/1970: [May 17, 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back)
>  4892 days after 1/1/1970: [May 25, 1983](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi)
>  16787 days after 1/1/1970: [December 18, 2015](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens)

The next two numbers may be

> [December 15, 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_VIII): 17515
>  [May 24, 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sequel_trilogy): 18040

Comment: The last one could be [17151](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_One). Great job, by the way +1

Comment: You are right !

Comment: What is the reason for the next two numbers?

Comment: @JörnBuitink Same encoding as all of the others. As to why I picked those numbers and not others, I followed the predictions in the Wikipedia pages I linked to (sorry for being vague, don't want to spoil the comments).

Comment: I actually tried this except counting away from the present date, not from an arbitrary date. Nice job finding this, turned the question from negative to positive which wouldn't have happened if this went on for a week :)

Comment: @Quark The date is not arbitrary, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time  But I did have the distinct advantage that I actually found the answer first (from the patterns in the sequence that should be obvious in hindsight), then reverse engineered the code

Comment: @ffao arbitrary probably wasn't the right word for me to use, it makes sense that if there was a starting time it'd be that one. I actually saw the whole series again in the past few months, sad I didn't get this but gj again.

Comment: @Quark This is my first question, can you please explain me why I get theese down vote (4) ? Is it to broad ? not clear ? not interesting ?

Comment: @Lordofdark It was very very vague when nobody knew even where to start. Pointing solvers in the right direction (even a topical hint after a day or so) would have probably gotten you a better score before a solution was found.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but an idea:

> Considering the hint "You can only add 2 numbers at the end at the moment. But if you take too much time to solve this, you may have to find more..." and the knowledge tag, I suspect that the answer has to do with occurrences of something.
>  7 occurrences are listed, and we can only list 2 more (at the moment). Therefore we are looking for something that has happened 9 times...
>  Those numbers could represent dates, or could encode information about these events in some way.
>  Although this idea hasn't gotten me anywhere yet, I'm thinking things like comet appearances, presidents... but I can't really get anywhere without knowing what kind of knowledge is needed.
> Edit:
>  However, looking at the 1st hint, it says we cannot be sure about the answer, although we can about the 1st part of the pattern. Perhaps this means 7 occurrences have taken place, whilst the 2 we can put for the answer are the next ones predicted which have not happened yet, and we aren't able to predict any more (for whatever reason).

Comment: You are on the right way ! Think about how you can group the numbers and the order

Comment: This was my first instinct as well, but I cannot get anything significant to match between them.  The last entry, 16787, indicates that the only possible format for a legitimate Gregorian date as D(D)M(M)YY.

Comment: What if the numbers are in pairs?

Answer (score 1):

maybe the two numbers are:

> 17878
>  18977

Reason:

> look at the first 3 numbers they are separated by 1093 and 1099
>  look at the second batch of three numbers they are separated by 1092 and 1099
>  so at the third one they must be separated by 1091 and 1099
>  it could be back to 1093 and 1099 but the hint says they are not the same so it must be different.

Comment: Please explain why!

Comment: @crybaba  No, sorry ;)

Comment: @crybaba This does not match the hint about uncertainty

Comment: Does it have to do with US tax forms?

Comment: @Z.Dailey no it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Something I saw:

> If you divide the numbers by 365 (days in a year) you get some unique numbers:
> 29.397..
> 32.392..
> 35.40..
> 7.40..
> 10.39..
> 13.40..
> 45.99..
> So whatever event it is, it seems linked to a solar cycle. By looking at the three clumps, it seems like crybaba's answer of 17878, 18977 could be close to the real answer.